ansible-builder unknown yaml key images
I'm trying to follow the instructions here for building an Execution Environment for Ansible.
When I run the following command:
ansible-builder build --tag postgresql_ee --container-runtime docker

I get the following error:
ansible_builder.exceptions.DefinitionError:
Error: Unknown yaml key(s), {'images'}, found in the definition file.

Allowed options are:
{'ansible_config', 'build_arg_defaults', 'dependencies', 'version', 'additional_build_steps'}

I'm using the following software versions:

Amazon Linux 2 (4.14.336-257.568.amzn2.x86_64)
Python 3.8.16
ansible-builder 1.2.0
ansible [core 2.13.13]
Docker 20.10.25

How do I fix the error?
I'm posting the YAML file here in case the webpage changes:
cat > execution-environment.yml<<EOF
version: 3

images:
  base_image:
    name: quay.io/fedora/fedora:latest

dependencies:
  ansible_core:
    package_pip: ansible-core
  ansible_runner:
    package_pip: ansible-runner
  system:
  - openssh-clients
  - sshpass
  galaxy:
    collections:
    - name: community.postgresql
EOF


Your ansible-builder version is propably to old for version: 3 environment. I am using 3.0.1 and the example is working.

ansible-builder 1.2.0 seems like a year-old version of the tool. Any particular reason for you not to get on the latest 3?

hi @mr.wolle @β.εηοιτ.βε, thank you for the tip. I installed ansible-builder by using this command python3 -m pip install --user ansible-builder and that was the version (1.2.0) that got automatically installed. I was using python 3.8.16.

Plus I think you'll need a version of python >= 3.9 to run the latest ansible-builder 3.

you have ansible-builder 1.2.0 and you are using version: 3 on you execution.
update your ansible-builder
ansible-builder 1.x dont have the option "images" i thinks jaja
pip3 install ansible-builder==3.0.0 or more
